# SQL Server : SUM Values and find the difference from two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following two tables and I want to find the difference between table 1 and table 2 for the month of "January". The difference should be the sum of all values for January in table 1 minus the sum of all values for the month of January in table 2.

The answer should be 300 (800 - 500), but my query keeps giving me the value "600".

My query is:

```
SELECT 
    a.month,
    (SUM(a.cost2)) - (SUM(b.cost2)) AS difference
FROM 
    Table1 a
LEFT JOIN 
    Table2 b ON a.Month = b.Month
WHERE 
    a.month = 'January'
GROUP BY 
    a.month
```

Table 1

```
Month    Cost2
--------------
January  500
February 400
March    300
April    600
January  300
March    200
March    400
April    200
```

Table 2

```
Month    Cost2
--------------
January  200
February 250
March    195
April    700
January  300
February 200
March    400
April    200
```

Comment: Learn to debug your own code. Remove the aggregates and the group by clause and just sort the joined rows by Month. You will see the rows that are generated and that will help you understand why the calculation is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

One method is to aggregate first and then `join`:

```
select a.month, (a_cost2 - b_cost2) as difference
from (select month, sum(a.cost2) as a_cost2
      from Table1 a
      where a.month = 'January'
      group by month
     ) a left join
     (select b.month, sum(b.cost2) as b_cost2
      from Table2 b
      where b.month = 'January'
      group by month
     ) b
     on a.Month = b.Month;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is actually what I was trying to do (subqueries), but my knowledge of it is pretty much non existent... thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are summing the values once for each row matching 'January' in A. This results in both values being doubled, and gives you double the difference.

To work around this, you must calculate the SUMmed values separately. Here is one way to do it:

```
select 'January'
    (SELECT sum(cost2) from Table1 where [month]='January') - 
    (SELECT sum(cost2) from Table2 where month='January') as difference
```

Comment: Obviously, in the real world, you would want a variable like '`DECLARE @month varchar(12)`, then assign the month  to the variable and substitute each use of the month's explicit name with the variable.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the explanation about the the values being doubled, it makes sense, but I'm not sure how to write out the full query. I tried the solution below and it seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, that was the full query. It should output what you need based on the filter.